# Amend the code so it doesn't show the position of the boats

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a battleships game, and it is a one player game that the coordinates of the ships are already hardcoded in and you are meant to guess where they are located. I'm having some trouble getting making it recognise which parts of the board is occupied by the ships and which aren't. At the moment, the whole board apparently isn't occupied by the ships and when I do enter coordinates that is occupied by a ship, it says that I have missed.

I don't want the board to display where the ships are, otherwise it will make the game too easy.

Here's my code below:

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim board(9, 9) As Char
    Dim bombs As Byte = 50
    Dim xcoord, ycoord, hits As Byte
    Dim gameover As Boolean

    Do
        Call displayallboard(board)
        Call getcoords(xcoord, ycoord)
        bombs = bombs - 1
        Call checkhit(xcoord, ycoord, board, hits)
        Call checkwins(hits, bombs, gameover)
    Loop Until gameover = True
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
    If hits = 16 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You win!!! All ships hit")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("You lose!!! You are out of ammunition")
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Sub displayallboard(ByRef board(,) As Char)
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("  |1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9")
    Console.WriteLine("--+------------------")
    For row = 1 To 9
        Console.Write(row & " |")
        For column = 1 To 9
            Console.Write(board(column, row) & " ")
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
End Sub
Sub addships(ByRef board(,) As Char, ByRef xcoord As Byte, ByRef ycoord As Byte)
    board(9, 1) = "S"
    board(9, 2) = "S"
    board(1, 2) = "S"
    board(1, 3) = "S"
    board(1, 4) = "S"
    board(1, 5) = "S"
    board(4, 4) = "S"
    board(5, 4) = "S"
    board(6, 4) = "S"
    board(4, 5) = "S"
    board(5, 5) = "S"
    board(6, 5) = "S"
    board(3, 8) = "S"
    board(4, 8) = "S"
    board(5, 8) = "S"
    board(6, 8) = "S"
End Sub
Sub getcoords(ByRef xcoord As Byte, ByRef ycoord As Byte)
    Console.Write("Enter the X coordinate: ")
    xcoord = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Enter the Y coordinate: ")
    ycoord = Console.ReadLine
End Sub
Sub checkhit(ByRef xcoord As Byte, ByRef ycoord As Byte, ByRef board(,) As Char, ByRef hits As Byte)
    Console.Clear()
    If board(xcoord, ycoord) = "S" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Hit!")
        hits = hits + 1
        board(xcoord, ycoord) = "X"
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Miss!")
        board(xcoord, ycoord) = "M"
    End If
End Sub
Sub checkwins(ByRef hits As Byte, ByRef bombs As Byte, ByRef gameover As Boolean)
    If hits = 50 Or bombs = 0 Then gameover = True
End Sub
End Module
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance I would say that you need a second array to keep the ship positions and check against this second array if the hit is on target or not

```
Dim shipPos(9, 9) As Char
```

Then change the addships subs to use this array

```
Sub addships(ByRef shipPos(,) As Char)
    shipPos(9, 1) = "S"
    shipPos(9, 2) = "S"
    shipPos(1, 2) = "S"
    shipPos(1, 3) = "S"
    shipPos(1, 4) = "S"
    shipPos(1, 5) = "S"
    shipPos(4, 4) = "S"
    shipPos(5, 4) = "S"
    shipPos(6, 4) = "S"
    shipPos(4, 5) = "S"
    shipPos(5, 5) = "S"
    shipPos(6, 5) = "S"
    shipPos(3, 8) = "S"
    shipPos(4, 8) = "S"
    shipPos(5, 8) = "S"
    shipPos(6, 8) = "S"
End Sub
```

Finally check the hit against the shipos array

```
Sub checkhit(ByRef xcoord As Byte, ByRef ycoord As Byte, ByRef board(,) As Char, ByRef hits As Byte)
    Console.Clear()
    If shipPos(xcoord, ycoord) = "S" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Hit!")
        hits = hits + 1
        board(xcoord, ycoord) = "X"
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Miss!")
        board(xcoord, ycoord) = "M"
    End If
End Sub
```

Also your actual code misses the call to `addships` and I think you need also an initialization routine that fills the board with a space otherwise the output display will not be correctly aligned.

```
addships(shippos)
initboard(board)
do
   ....
while
```

These problems are easy to fix, however a more complex algorithm is required to position these ships in random positions without conflicts between them